# I'm trying to work in localhost(windows 10) but the s.accept() not responding

Tags: python, networking

I'm trying to develop a sender & reciver network in my laptop(localhost). the code is working well before s.accept() , but after that nothing is happening or (compiling may be). I've checked by printing 2 string "ok1" & "ok2". "ok1" is showing but "ok2" never , so s.accept() not working as far I understood. How to fix this please...[i'm new in socket]

code below:

```
s.listen(5)
print('Sender ready and is listening')
while (True):
    # to accept all incoming connections
    print("ok1")#its printing 
    clientsocket, address = s.accept()
    print("ok2")#its not printing
    print("Receiver " + str(address) + " connected")
    # create a different thread for every
    # incoming connection
    client(clientsocket, address)
```

Comment: This should work. How do you try to connect to your server socket?

Comment: @Serge I've uploaded the sender & reciver file. i'll glad if u see it please.   sender: https://pastebin.com/wtYiCt8f   reciver: https://pastebin.com/L2EcUYka

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Python 3.6: I started `server.py` in one window (console) and it printed up to `ok1`. Then I started `receiver.py` in another console, and I got `ok2`, `Receiver ('127.0.0.1', xxxx) connected` (xxxx being the random port), again `ok1` and an error `File "C:\...\sender.py", line 40, in run
    bitstring = str(raw_input("enter bit string"))
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined`. `raw_input` is an old Python2 function and is just `input` in Python3.